# Use twitter bootstrap css class in the ckeditor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I want to use the bootstrap class in the ckeditor 4. But I found the ckeditor will remove the class if I input the class in the source mode. And I want to allow user to select the class from the ckedtior css dropdown list and then show the style directly.
Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

The solution is actually a combination of two of these answers by Andrey Nelubin and user3250006.

Firstly, in order to force CKEditor to keep your custom HTML and class attributes, you need the `allowedContent = true` configuration. After that, in order to actually see the formatting in the editor, you need to add an extra path to `contentsCss` (perhaps your main CSS file, or a subset that just includes Bootstrap).

So, the following works for me:

```
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            contentsCss: [CKEDITOR.basePath + 'contents.css', '/path/to/custom.css'],
            allowedContent: true,
        });
```

Comment: contentsCss is ignored for inline and full page editors. (Just discovered that after spending ages wondering why it didn't seem to do anything.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set extra css:

```
$(function () {
    CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.basePath + 'contents.css', '/path/to/your/css']
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1'); // or another instance
});
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey. after added the CKEDITOR.config.contentCss = [...], it still wll remove my custom class. for example:
I input <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="span6"><p>2</p></div>
</div>

but it will change to below after change to the edit mode from source mode:
<p>1</p>

<p>2</p>

Comment: Hm.. can you make the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

user3250006 is half right, then you need to add
    `CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'p,span,h1,h2,h3(class1,class2),img,strong,em(class3)';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the js that's setting up the editor:

> CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;

This worked for me when I needed to pass in bootstrap classes in content templates.